# Compose Navigation destination that matches request NavDeepLinkRequest cannot be found in the navigation graph NavGraph

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

Here my set up:

@Composable
fun MyNavHost(navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController(), padding: PaddingValues) {
val actions = remember(navController) { MainActions(navController) }

```
NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = TopLevelDestination.Home.route, modifier = Modifier.padding(padding)
) {
    composable(TopLevelDestination.Home.route) {
        HomeScreen(onNavigateToArticle = actions.navigateToArticle)
    }
    composable(
        "${MyRoute.ARTICLE_ROUTE}/${MyRoute.ARTICLE_ID}",
        arguments = listOf(navArgument(MyRoute.DATE_KEY) { type = NavType.LongType })
    ) { backStackEntry ->
        ArticleScreen(
            articleId = backStackEntry.arguments?.getLong(MyRoute.ARTICLE_ID)!!
        )
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Models the navigation actions in the app.
 */
class MainActions(navController: NavHostController) {
    val navigateToArticle: (Long) -> Unit = { articleId: Long ->
        navController.navigate("${MyRoute.ARTICLE_ROUTE}/${articleId}")
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the Article Item from a lazy column which is clickable

```
 Row(
    modifier = modifier
        .clickable { onNavigateToArticle(articleId) }
        .padding(10.dp)
        .heightIn(72.dp),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
)
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation destination that matches request 
NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/article/16788348 } cannot 
be found in the navigation graph NavGraph(0x0) startDestination=. 
{Destination(0xa2d96fd4) route=home}
```

I read this [article](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nav-with-args) and it seemed pretty straightforward. I can't really figured out what I am doing wrong.
I read some answers on stackoverflow already. unfortunately they don't apply to my case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of:

```
"${MyRoute.ARTICLE_ROUTE}/${MyRoute.ARTICLE_ID}"
```

I just had to write

```
"${MyRoute.ARTICLE_ROUTE}/{${MyRoute.ARTICLE_ID}}"
                          ^                     ^
                          |                     |
                            extra brackets here
```

So one pair more of bracket (around the argument).